# Angular2 component view does not update on value change via method

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular2 I am creating a modal window which needs to be toggled on and off. During the development I stumbled upon something weird:

When I change the `activate` variable inside my `Modal class` with an external button. The view is not updating.

Printing the `activate` variable in the console goes without any problem. I see the variable toggle between true and false.

It looks like I am missing code which forces the view to render with the new values.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be missing here?

The code below in a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IMywtz6H8rkf4bvMQm2i?p=preview)

**app.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Modal} from './modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [Modal],
  template: `
    <div>

      <button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>

      <button (click)="showActivate()">print</button>

      <modal></modal>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Modal]
})
export class App {
  constructor(private modal: Modal) {

  }

  showActivate() {
    this.modal.showActivate();
  }

  toggle() {
    this.modal.toggleActivate();
  }
}
```

**modal.ts**

```
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Modal: {{activate}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})

@Injectable()
export class Modal {

  activate: true;

  constructor() {
    this.activate = false;
  }

  showActivate() {
    console.log('Modal:showActivate', this.activate);
  }

  toggleActivate() {
    console.log('Modal:toggleActivate', this.activate);
    this.activate = !this.activate;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you inject a modal and get a modal, doesn't mean it is the modal instance you want. If you list it in `providers` Angular DI just creates an instance and passes it in, but this instance is not related to the `<modal>` tag at all

Use instead `@ViewChild()` to get a reference

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xMXMs0WAHueFKmuX8wD1?p=preview)

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>

      <button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>

      <button (click)="showActivate()">print</button>

      <modal #modal></modal>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Modal]
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('modal') modal;
  constructor() {

  }

  showActivate() {
    this.modal.showActivate();
  }

  toggle() {
    this.modal.toggleActivate();
  }
}
```

For your example code it isn't necessary to get a direct reference at all anyway. You can use binding with `@Input()` and `@Output()`. If the component and the modal are not that closely related (if you use a global modal instance that can be utilized by the entire application a shared service with an `Observable` that notifies about value changes might be a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

**[working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BI0NLASJGlcVG4MWTnng?p=preview)**

I have changed **providers** to **directives** like,

```
directives: [Modal]
```

And I'm using `@ViewChild` to get access of **ModalCmp**.

**app.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component,ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
import {Modal} from './modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Modal],
  template: `
    <div>

      <button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>

      <button (click)="showActivate()">print</button>

      <modal></modal>

    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild(Modal) vc:Modal;
  constructor() {

  }

  showActivate() {
    this.vc.showActivate();
  }

  toggle() {
    this.vc.toggleActivate();
  }
}
```

**Modal.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Modal: {{activate}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})

//@Injectable()
export class Modal {

  activate: true;

  constructor() {
    this.activate = false;
  }

  showActivate() {
    console.log('Modal:showActivate', this.activate);
  }

  toggleActivate() {
    this.activate = !this.activate;
    console.log('Modal:toggleActivate', this.activate);

    console.log(this.activate)
  }

}
```