# Connection between two Angular 2 components view not updating

Tags: typescript, angular

I've got a slight variation on the question posted here: [Angular2 component view does not update on value change via method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154446/angular2-component-view-does-not-update-on-value-change-via-method).

I want to switch a variable on the `modal component` from the `toggle buttons component` but the view is not updated.

How can I make the modal view update when I click the toggle button?

See for reference: [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9KJdnxk1DKF6ngxreJmV)

**app.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
import {Modal} from './modal';
import {ToggleButtons} from './togglebuttons';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>

       <toggle-buttons></toggle-buttons>

       <modal></modal>

    </div>
  `,
  providers: [Modal, ToggleButtons, ],
})
export class App {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**togglebuttons.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Modal} from './modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'toggle-buttons',
  template: `
    <div>

      <button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>

      <button (click)="showActivate()">print</button>

    </div>
  `
})
export class ToggleButtons {
  constructor(private modal: Modal) {

  }

  showActivate() {
    this.modal.showActivate();
  }

  toggle() {
    this.modal.toggleActivate();
  }
}
```

**modal.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Modal: {{activate}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})

export class Modal {

  activate: true;

  constructor() {
    this.activate = false;
  }

  showActivate() {
    console.log('Modal:showActivate', this.activate);
  }

  toggleActivate() {
    this.activate = !this.activate;
    console.log('Modal:toggleActivate', this.activate);

    console.log(this.activate)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the modal and provide it as an input to your `Toggle` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <toggle-buttons [modal]="modal"></toggle-buttons>
      <modal></modal>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Modal, ToggleButtons],
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild(Modal)
  modal: Modal;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

This input must be defined like this in your `Toggle` component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class ToggleButtons {
  @Input()
  modal:Modal;

  (...)
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/3t5xo9Y6N8iEL4eqw9Gn?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I've checked out your plunkr but the view is not updating when I press the toggle button. Is the url correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, a `providers` attribute remained ;-) I should be fixed now... If you could have a look

Comment: I'm sorry, i've checked it again but the view is not updating. Is it possible you have an incorrect url for your plunkr?

Comment: Really. On this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/3t5xo9Y6N8iEL4eqw9Gn?p=preview and when you click on the "toggle" button?

Comment: Yes, what I expected to happen was that when you click the toggle button the Modal: false in the view would update to Modal: true.

Comment: Yes, I have this behavior on my side ;-) Really strange. What do you have on your side (at the level of the view and the console)?

Comment: When clicking the toggle button in the console:
Modal:toggleActivate true true
Modal:toggleActivate false false

and in In the view:
Modal: false
Modal: false

Comment: I had previously this behavior because its remained a `providers` attribute with `Modal` in it in the `Toggle` component... I removed it and it fixed this problem.

Comment: Do you have this on your side?

Comment: For some mysterious reason it is working now! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The `Modal` instance injected to

```
export class Toggle {
  constructor(private modal: Modal) {

  }
```

is some arbitrary instance created by Angular DI and not related to the `<modal></modal>` element at all, therefore calling or changing properties doesn't have any effect on the view of `App`